# Rails, NGINX does not load deployed application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

I have installed last stable version of NGINX (1.10)

In my Rails project I have created `nginx.conf` file:

```
upstream puma_myapp {
  server unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/myapp/current/public;
  access_log /var/www/myapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/myapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma_myapp;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I have deploy my rails application via capistrano. It deamonized my application.

Now in `/etc/nginx` there is no `sites-enabled` folder. I have created this folder then I have written this:

```
sudo ln -nfs "/var/www/myapp/current/config/nginx.conf" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp"
```

Then I restart my nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

When I open my page address, I still get nginx's default page, why this is happening?

My `puma.rb` file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/var/www/myapp/current'
rackup "/var/www/myapp/current/config.ru"
environment 'production'

pidfile "/var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/var/www/myapp/current/log/puma.error.log', '/var/www/myapp/current/log/puma.access.log', true



threads 4,16

bind 'unix:///var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock

workers 0
```

My `var/log/nginx/error.log` file shows this:

```
2016/08/16 10:07:01 [error] 10157#10157: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 178.88.194.6, server: localhost, $
2016/08/16 10:14:49 [error] 10157#10157: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 203.110.167.86, $
2016/08/16 10:14:55 [error] 10157#10157: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pma/scripts/setup.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 203.110.167.86, server:$
2016/08/16 10:15:00 [error] 10157#10157: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/myadmin/scripts/setup.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 203.110.167.86, ser$
2016/08/16 10:36:20 [error] 26599#26599: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 178.88.194.6, server: localhost, reques$
2016/08/16 10:42:11 [error] 27962#27962: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 178.88.194.6, server: localhost, reques$
```

Comment: Can you also post your `puma.rb`?

Comment: I did just now realize your small hint that there was no `sites-enabled` folder. Which opertating system do you use? Did you install nginx via package manager? When `sites-enabled` didn't exits this can mean your nginx does not include the configs within `sites-enabled` and you have to add `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`within your nginx.conf

Comment: Try using `listen` instead of `bind` in your unicorn puma.rb file and what's the output of your puma error log say?  Do you have any errors in nginx at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or any other logs you specify above?

Comment: Also, you don't need `///` after `unix:` for your socket path, one slash is sufficient.

Comment: One more tip:  don't use try_files, unless you have a good reason to.  Its a lot slower since it has to scan for the files on each request.

Comment: @yekta I don't use `unicorn`, I use `puma`

Comment: I meant after unix, in your nginx config.  Without knowing what your nginx logs are saying, we're all in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sites-enabled` directory is a Debian package specific feature. If you have installed other nginx package or built it yourself, then the `nginx.conf` is likely doesn't contain the `include /etc/nginx/sites-en‌​a‌​bled/*;` directive, and configuration files from this directory are not included.

Comment: I'll just add that its best to install from the system package rather than building it yourself, that way you a) don't run into weird problems like this and b) make it easier to stay up to date with security updates for nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Your bind socket within `puma.rb` does not match your socket within `nginx.conf`

**Edit after question update:**

PMA? It seems like you'r using plesk to adminstrate your system. plesk generates a lot of stuff. You have to check where plesk want's your configs.

Comment: Ok, for nginx.conf `unix:/var/www/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock;`  should be sufficient. I don't know if it is an issue when you add additional `/`. Does `puma.error.log` or `nginx.error.log info` provide any info?

Comment: `puma.error.log` shows messages that it has been demonized. One interesting thing is that there is no `nginx.error.log` file. It is like nginx is ignoring `sites-enabled` folder. In other VPS I had NGINX `1.4` which works fine, but in this where `1.10` is located, this happens.

Comment: I bet that your config is not included.

Comment: Why, when I open `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` it has, It is even updates when I change `nginx.conf` file in my project. Does this `1.10` version has some kind of difference in working with `sites-enabled` against `1.4` version ?

Comment: Did you check `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` ? Is within nginx.conf a statement to include `/etc/nginx/sites-ena‌​bled/*` ? This folder is not included by default. It sounds strange that the folder `/etc/nginx/sites-en‌​abled` didn't exists in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121033/discussion-between-slowjack2k-and-mr-d).